# Is it possible to set tile entity data on an enderman's held block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a specific command that I can do to summon an enderman holding a command block with a custom command preset?

I tried the following command, but the command block doesn't have a command inside:

```
summon minecraft:enderman ~ ~ ~ {carriedBlockState:{Name:"minecraft:command_block"},TileEntityData:{Command:"time set 1000"}}
```

Comment: What edition is this? Java or bedrock?

Comment: Minecraft Java Edition

Comment: I did /summon enderman ~ ~ ~ {carriedBlockState:{Name:"minecraft:command_block"},TileEntityData:{Command:"time set 1000"}}, but once when the enderman places the command block down, there is no command set inside the command block

Comment: looking at the nbt of an enderman, it looks like endermen only store the state of the block they are holding (which is used to display the block model), but that's about it

Comment: I'm making this into a canonical for any tile entity data on an enderman's held block.

Comment: If it's 1.16 it could be this:
/summon enderman ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1b,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"time set 1000"}}},{}],carriedBlockState:{Name:"minecraft:command_block"}}

Answer (score -1):

Summoning Enderman with command block holding custom command and placing detection:

```
/summon minecraft:enderman ~ ~1 ~ {carriedBlockState:{Name:"minecraft:command_block"},HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1b,tag:{Command:"/say Hello from the Enderman!"}},{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b}],Tags:["place_command_block"]}
```

Repeating command block to detect placement of command block and execute
custom command:

```
execute as @e[type=command_block,nbt={id:"minecraft:command_block"},tag=place_command_block] run say The Enderman has placed a command block!
```

This is what I came up with. I don't know if it works, but maybe you could test it. If it doesn't, then ask me :).

Comment: Thanks for reaching back to this 2 year old thread. Unfortunately, I tried using the command in 1.16.5, 1.19.4, and 1.20 pre-release 1 and it doesn't work as the command block that the enderman placed down is empty

Comment: @InfinitySwordofDiamond pretty sure u cant specify a command, only blockstates. the carried block and hand item are 2 different items. checking in mcstacker, there is no way to do it there either

Answer (score -1):

I'm not at the opportunity to test this but looks like the following should work :

```
/summon enderman ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,tag:{Command:"say Hello, Enderman!"}}]}
```

In this command:

- **summon enderman:** This part of the command summons an Enderman.
- **~ ~1 ~:** This sets the position of the summoned Enderman. You can adjust the coordinates as needed.
- **{HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:command_block", Count:1** This specifies the items the Enderman is holding.
- **,tag:{Command:"your_custom_command"}}]}:** Replace "your_custom_command" with the actual command you want the command block to execute.This key-value pair is part of the item's "tag" property, which can be used to store additional data. In this case, it's specifying a custom command to be stored in the command block. Replace "your_custom_command" with the actual command you want the command block to execute.

Comment: I tested it out in both 1.16.5 and 1.20.4, but the enderman doesn't hold anything after I summoned it using this command and it also didn't drop any command blocks at all.